# getting auto-width to work with absolute position from left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply absolute position on an error label elemennt, which is inside an input field that is also positioned absolutely. The problem is that auto-width on the error element won't apply correctly, and will break after the first word. Why is that happening? If I use position right instead of left, it seems to work fine. Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/u793ata5/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="inside">
        <label class="error">Show this error on the side</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#outside {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

#inside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    left: 40%;
    width: 80%;
}

.error {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 10%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: what's your expected output..?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/u793ata5/2/) what you wanted??

Comment: Why don't you simply set `width: 100%` instead of `auto`? That way `.error` will have some "fixed" width depending on its container, and the text will wrap automatically eitherway.

Answer (score 2):

Why so many absolutely positioned elements? Maybe I'm not understanding what you want the layout to look like--and maybe you could clarify--but this modified fiddle looks more reasonable to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/u793ata5/3/

```
.error {
     background-color: red;
     display: block;
     margin-left: 50%;
     color: white;
}
```

I try not to use position: absolute unless I...uh absolutely have to.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state it clear enough, but the problem is that I don't want .error to be wrapped in #inside div - I want it to stick out of it at 90% position from the left.

Comment: I don't think the .error element can inherit a width from its parent, so width: auto isn't going to work. There are ways to fake width: auto (left: 0, right: 0) on an absolutely positioned element INSIDE its parent, but not outside. If you're determined to have nested position: absolute elements, one outside the other, I think you're either going to have to provide a static width or fall back to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting it's position at 90% from the left. This means it only has 10% of the parent width to place text before wrapping. Try using

```
float: right;
```

instead of

```
left: 90%;
```

Comment: What if I want to start it at 90% position of #inside div and I want it to be outside (not wrapped in #inside div).

Comment: You're placing the label inside the div, but you want it to be positioned on the outside of the div? Or do you want the error label positioned inside the #inside div at 90% from the left side of the #inside div and prevent it from wrapping when it reaches the right most border of the #inside div?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be outside of #inside (prevent it from wraping when it reaches the most border of #inside), starting from 90% position from the left from #inside div.